# -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart works but -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp does not?

Tags: java, maven

I was watching a tutorial and this statement totally works on the instructor's computer/cmd:

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupdId=com.newApp -DartifactId=sampleWeb -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinterfaceMode=false

Also, the same with -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart.

However, this fails to run on mine:maven-archetype-webapp but maven-archetype-quickstart works on mine. Any clues why? and what should I do?

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Do you have an error message when the command fail ? If yes please add it to your question. Adding the link to the tutorial would be a good idea.

Comment: Yea, this is the problem with old tutorials.  They get out of date, and the person who created the tutorial is often not motivated to re-make them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the new version of Maven probably requires to mention version of archetype in the command.

Therefore an addition of "-DarchetypeVersion=1.3" needs to be added in the command (anywhere) and then it shall run. Especially if you are having BUILD FAILURE as :

" The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0) -> [Help 1] "

Therefore the command should be something like: 
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.lynda -DartifactId=sampleWeb -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.3

Reference: Check **Usage** at https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/

Answer (score 0):

You can track the different ArchetypeVersion by following the link for the **maven-archetype-webapp** archetypeArtifactId:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/

Here is the one I've used:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.pluralsight.javaee-getting-started -DartifactId=bookstore-back -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false -Dpackage=com.pluralsight.bookstore
```